# Make an Event When Second Form IsClosing

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms

Let me say I have 2 forms

> 1st form name is : **Form1**
>
> Consists from : 1 Button and it's name is `Button1`

This Button is `Public` from its `properties` and have an OnClick event

**The event is:**

```
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
        Button1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

> 2nd Form name is : **Form2**
>
> Consists from : `nothing`

But there's a FormClosing event

**The event is:**

```
        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Which means `Button1` from `Form1` should be `Enabled` again.

> **The problem nothing happens when the Form2 is Closed**

I thought that event is incorrect but i'm not really sure

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the instance of Form1 to Form2, that way you have access to the object/form...

```
public class Form2
{
  private Form1 _Form1;
  public Form2(Form1 form1)
  {
     this._Form1 = form1;
  }

  private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
      _Form1.Button1.Enabled = true;
  }    
}
```

...

```
public class Form1
{
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Form2 form2 = new Form2(this); //pass "this", ie the instance of Form1
    form2.Show();
    Button1.Enabled = false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks For The Epic and simple Answer!
Working 100%